# Code for Factorial Function

Tags: programming

Below I have my code that I created for finding the factorial of a number. The output I am getting when I enter `MyFact[5]` is `Null Return[120]`.
I am rather new to Mathematica so I feel its a small semantic problem, but any help would be appreciated!

```
MyFact[n_] :=
  Module [
        {
         OneAgoFact,
         MyNewFact,
         Counter
        },
  MyNewFact = 1;
  OneAgoFact = 1;
  If[ n > 0,
    Counter = 1;
    While[Counter <= n,
        MyNewFact = OneAgoFact*Counter; 
        OneAgoFact = MyNewFact;
        Counter = Counter + 1;
        ]
        ]
   Return[MyNewFact]
  ]
```

Comment: You forgot to put a semicolon at the end of your `If[]`. If you do that, you can remove the `Return[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Turning [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155137/code-for-factorial-function#comment414101_155137) into an answer, you need to follow the `If[...]` statement with a semicolon.  Otherwise `If` evaluates to what `While` evaluates to, which is `Null`, and without the semicolon *Mathematica* interprets `If[...] Return[...]` as multiplication.

```
ClearAll[MyFact]
MyFact[n_] := Module[{OneAgoFact, MyNewFact, Counter}, MyNewFact = 1;
  OneAgoFact = 1;
  If[n > 0, Counter = 1;
   While[Counter <= n, MyNewFact = OneAgoFact*Counter;
    OneAgoFact = MyNewFact;
    Counter = Counter + 1;]];
   MyNewFact]
```

Notice that you can replace `Return[MyNewFact]` simply with `MyNewFact`, as `Module` returns the evaluated form of its second argument.

One last note:  you might want to avoid capital letters at the start of variable names, as they often conflict with built-in symbols.   Symbols (i.e., variables or functions) which start with lowercase letters will never conflict with built-ins.  Of course this is up to you.